# Powershell to Validate Email addresses

Tags: powershell, validation, email

I'm trying to get Powershell to validate email addresses using Regex and put email addresses into good and bad csv files. I can get it to skip one line and write to file, but cannot get it to target the email addresses and validate them, then write lines to good and bad files. I can do it in C# and JavaScript, but have never done it in Powershell. I know this can be done, but not sure how.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Function IsValidEmail { 
    Param ([string] $In) 
    # Returns true if In is in valid e-mail format. 
    [system.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch($In,  
        "^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|
    (([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$");  
} 


## Now we need to check the original file for invalid and valid emails.**

$list = Get-Content C:\Emails\OriginalEmails\emailAddresses.csv

# This way we also use the foreach loop.
##======= Test to see if the file exists ===========

if (!(Test-Path "C:\Emails\ValidEmails\ValidEmails.csv")) {
    New-Item -path C:\Emails\ValidEmails -name ValidEmails.csv -type 
    "file" # -value "my new text"
    Write-Host "Created new file and text content added"
}
else {
    ## Add-Content -path C:\Share\sample.txt -value "new text content"
    Write-Host "File already exists and new text content added"
}


if (!(Test-Path "C:\Emails\InValidEmails\InValidEmails.csv")) {
    New-Item -path C:\Emails\InValidEmails -name InValidEmails.csv -type 
    "file" # -value "my new text"
    Write-Host "Created new file and text content added"
}
else {
    # Add-Content -path C:\Emails\ValidEmails -value "new text content"
    Write-Host "File already exists and new text content added"
}

#$Addresses = Import-Csv "C:\Data\Addresses.csv" -Header 
Name, Address, PhoneNumber | Select -Skip 1
$EmailAddressImp = Import-Csv 
"C:\Emails\OriginalEmails\emailAddresses.csv" -Header 
FirstName, LastName, Email, Address, City, State, ZipCode  | Select  
FirstName, LastName, Email, Address, City, State, ZipCode -Skip 1
```

## I'm validating the third column "Email" in the original csv file and trying to write out the whole row to file (good file, bad file). Not sure how to buffer either doing this.

```
ForEach ($emailAddress in $list) { 
    if (IsValidEmail($emailAddress)) { 
        "Valid: {0}" -f $emailAddress
        Out-File -Append C:\Emails\ValidEmails\ValidEmails.csv -Encoding UTF8
        $EmailAddressImp | Export-Csv "C:\Emails\ValidEmails\ValidEmails.csv" 
        -NoTypeInformation
    } 
    else { 
        "Invalid: {0}" -f $emailAddress 
        Out-File -Append C:\Emails\InValidEmails\InValidEmails.csv -
        Encoding UTF8
        $EmailAddressImp | Export-Csv 
        "C:\Emails\InValidEmails\InValidEmails.csv" -NoTypeInformation
    }     
}
```

Comment: Hi, you might like to use a service that actually checks if the email is valid, not just syntactically but that it actually exists. You could use something like http://isitarealemail.com which supports csv file validating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each of the current top 2 answers here has one significant deficiency:

@Trevor's answer would do just fine, until you supply it this:

```
John Doe <johndoe@somewhere.com>
```

@Mathias' answer preaches about accommodating exceptional (yet valid) addresses such as those with non-ASCII or no TLD suffix. The following addresses all validate successfully with the `[mailaddress]` casting:

```
olly@somewhere | olly@somewhere. | olly@somewhere...com  etc
```

If, like me, you will not be entertaining these edge cases into your email databases, then a combination of both ideas might prove more useful, like so:

```
function IsValidEmail { 
    param([string]$Email)
    $Regex = '^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$'

   try {
        $obj = [mailaddress]$Email
        if($obj.Address -match $Regex){
            return $True
        }
        return $False
    }
    catch {
        return $False
    } 
}
```

Perhaps there is a performance overhead with creating `$obj` for every email address on a possibly long mailing list. But I guess that's another matter.

Comment: [mailaddress]'John Doe <johndoe@somewhere.com>' works fine! And have a look at the output...

Comment: The regular expression is not correct. top level domains can have more than 3 letters.

Answer (score 20):

> I'm trying to get Powershell to validate email addresses using Regex

## Don't!

I would recommend against this. Accurately validating email addresses using regular expressions can be *much more difficult* than you might think.

Let's have a look at your regex pattern:

```
^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

In it's current form it incorrectly validates `.@domain.tld`.

On the other hand, it doesn't validate unicode-encoded internationalized domain names, like `user@☎.com` (yes, that's a valid email address)

---

Instead of trying to find or construct a perfect email validation regex pattern, I would use the `MailAddress` class for validation instead:

```
function IsValidEmail { 
    param([string]$EmailAddress)

    try {
        $null = [mailaddress]$EmailAddress
        return $true
    }
    catch {
        return $false
    }
}
```

If the input string is a valid email address, the cast to `[mailaddress]` will succeed and the function return `$true` - if not, the cast will result in an exception, and it returns `$false`.

---

When exporting the data, I'd consider collecting *all* the results at once in memory and then writing it to file *once*, at the end.

If you're using PowerShell version 2 or 3, you can do the same with two passes of `Where-Object`:

```
$EmailAddresses = Import-Csv "C:\Emails\OriginalEmails\emailAddresses.csv" -Header FirstName, LastName, Email, Address, City, State, ZipCode  | Select -Skip 1

$valid   = $list |Where-Object {IsValidEmail $_.Email}
$invalid = $list |Where-Object {-not(IsValidEmail $_.Email)}
```

If you're using PowerShell version 4.0 or newer, I'd suggest using the `.Where()` extension method in `Split` mode:

```
$EmailAddresses = Import-Csv "C:\Emails\OriginalEmails\emailAddresses.csv" -Header FirstName, LastName, Email, Address, City, State, ZipCode  | Select -Skip 1

$valid,$invalid = $list.Where({IsValidEmail $_.Email}, 'Split')
```

before exporting to file:

```
if($valid.Count -gt 0){ 
    $valid |Export-Csv "C:\Emails\ValidEmails\ValidEmails.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
if($invalid.Count -gt 0){ 
    $invalid |Export-Csv "C:\Emails\ValidEmails\InvalidEmails.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: `[MailAddress]"me@myself..com"` is incorrectly validated.

Comment: `olly@somewhere`, `olly@somewhere.` and `olly@somewhere...com` ALL come out valid with this!!! Should they?

Comment: They are all RFC-valid mail addresses :) a second validation step could be MX resolution for `([mailaddress]olly@somewhere.).Host`

Comment: If, like me, you struggled to find the docs on the `.Where()` operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.3#where

Answer (score 8):

You can just use the `-match` operator, instead of calling into the `[Regex]` class. Here's a simple example, without any wrapper function:

```
$EmailRegex = '^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$'

$EmailList = @('a@a.com', 'b@b.co', 'm.a@example.il')

foreach ($Email in $EmailList) {
  $DidItMatch = $Email -match $EmailRegex
  if ($DidItMatch) {
    # It matched! Do something.
  }
  else {
    # It didn't match
  }
}
```

FYI, when you use the `-match` operator, if it returns boolean `$true`, then PowerShell automatically populates a built-in (aka. "automatic") variable called `$matches`. To avoid unexpected behavior, you might want to reset this variable to `$null` during each iteration, or just wrap it in a function as you did in your original example. This will keep the variable scoped to the function level, as long as you don't declare it in one of the parent scopes.

Once you've validated the e-mail address, you can append it to your existing CSV file, using:

```
Export-Csv -Append -FilePath filepath.csv -InputObject $Email
```

For efficiency with the available filesystem resources, you'll probably want to buffer a few e-mail addresses in memory, before appending them to your target CSV file.

```
# Initialize a couple array buffers
$ValidEmails = @()
$InvalidEmails = @()

if ($ValidEmails.Count -gt 50) {
  # Run the CSV export here
}

if ($Invalid.Count -gt $50) {
  # Run the CSV export here
}
```

If you need further help, can you please edit your question and clarify what isn't working for you?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, but I am trying to validate the third column "Email" in a CSV file and then write the whole line out that has a good or bad email address to one of the two files (good email, bad email). I only had the strings there for testing. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You have been so awesome in helping... I know that the other guy doesn't want me to use Regex, but it was an experiment that matches the same as the other programming languages (C#, JavaScript). The idea was to use Regex to do validation. I know this may not be the best practice, but this was the instructions that I was given (criteria).

Comment: @ChrisSingleton Happy to help, Chris. Hopefully you can adapt this to your CSV structure. That might warrant a separate question. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `mailaddress` type to ensure it meets RFC, but you will likely still want to make sure the domain is valid:

```
Resolve-DnsName -Name ('vertigoray@example.com' -as [mailaddress]).Host -Type 'MX'
```

Works well as a validation script for a function parameter:

```
function Assert-FromEmail {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateScript({ Resolve-DnsName -Name $_.Host -Type 'MX' })]
        [mailaddress]
        $From
    )

    Write-Output $From
}
```

Output examples of that function on success:

```
PS > Assert-FromEmail -From vertigoray@example.com

DisplayName User       Host        Address
----------- ----       ----        -------
            vertigoray example.com vertigoray@example.com
```

Output examples of that function on failure:

```
PS > Assert-FromEmail -From vertigoray@example..com
Assert-FromEmail : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'From'. The " Resolve-DnsName -Name $_.Host -Type 'MX' "validation script for the argument with value "vertigoray@example..com" did not return a result of True. Determine why the validation script failed, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:24
+ Assert-FromEmail -From vertigoray@example..com
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Assert-FromEmail], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Assert-FromEmail
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one to try I wrote up and tested and has not failed me in any environment to date. Not, saying it won't in someone else's, but for me, it's been 100%.

```
$SomeEmailAddresses = @'
From:JoeBob@yahoo.com,Tom TheCat tcat@snailmail.net,jerry@snailmail.net 
To:TulaJane@hotmail.com;JF@gmail.com;tiger@outlook.com; 
Doug Tompson DTompson@icloud.com 
MailTo:BobsYourUncle@protonmail.com; 
johnny.bravo@yahoo.co.uk
'@

(((Select-String -InputObject $SomeEmailAddresses `
-Pattern '\w+@\w+\.\w+|\w+\.\w+@\w+\.\w+\.\w+' `
-AllMatches).Matches).Value)


Rsults 

JoeBob@yahoo.com
tcat@snailmail.net
jerry@snailmail.net
TulaJane@hotmail.com
JF@gmail.com
tiger@outlook.com
DTompson@icloud.com
BobsYourUncle@protonmail.com
johnny.bravo@yahoo.co.uk
```

Answer (score 0):

@postanote

This common email formatting fails

$SomeEmailAddresses = @'
First A. Last first.a.last@gmail.com.
'@

(((Select-String -InputObject $SomeEmailAddresses `-Pattern '\w+@\w+\.\w+|\w+\.\w+@\w+\.\w+\.\w+'`
-AllMatches).Matches).Value)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use.
The regex does not support the following because the major email players do not support.

Domains as IP addresses.

Space and special characters "(),:;<>@[] inside a quoted string in local-part.

Comments within parentheses in local-part.

$email = "^(?(?=^(?:([a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+-/=?^`{|}~]+|[a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^`{|}~].[a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+-/=?^`{|}~][\.a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^`{|}~]*)*)@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{1,63}$)[a-zA-Z0-9_.!#$%&'*+-/=?^`{|}~]{1,63}@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,})+)$"

$email -match $regexPattern